# Python TypeError takes 2 positional arguments but 3 are given

Tags: python, function, runtime-error

This code is supposed to calculate the shortest Manhattan distance between a node state (character position) and the nearest food location.

`state = ((x, y), ("some status"))`

`food_coords = [(x, y), (x, y), (x, y)]`

note: (x,y) are some coordinates in a grid

But, when the `get_manhattan_distance(pos, food_pos)` executes, I get the following error:
`TypeError: GridProblem.get_manhattan_distance() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

note: when this function is called, the character (state position) and the food position are on the same grid location.

```
# helper function to calculate the manhattan distance
def get_manhattan_distance(p, q):
    distance = 0
    for p_i,q_i in zip(p,q):
        distance += abs(p_i - q_i)
    return distance

# heuristic = Manhattan distance
def h(self, node):
    if self.is_goal(node.state):
        return 0
    pos = node.state[0] #current position (x, y)
    x_coord = node.state[0][0]
    y_coord = node.state[0][1]
    distances = []
    for food_pos in self.food_coords:
        print('pos=',pos)
        print('food_pos=',pos)
        distances.append(self.get_manhattan_distance(pos, food_pos))
    distances.sort()
    return distances[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Every method of a class, receives its object as input. That is what "self" parameter in the method definition refers to. Just add self parameter to your get_manhattan_distance method definition and the problem will be gone. like this:

```
get_manhattan_distance(self, p, q):
```